# Mod_Rewrite URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Current URL:

```
http://localhost/blog/profile.php?username=Username&page_type=following
```

I want it to be:

```
http://localhost/blog/profile/Username/following
```

Current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
CheckCaseOnly On
CheckSpelling On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ /blog/profile.php?username=$1&page_type=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Is it possible to rewrite it this way? Or are there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You need two capture groups:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*?)/(.*)$ /blog/profile.php?username=$1&page_type=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `$2` for the `page_type` in the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) pattern

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*?)/(.*)$ /blog/profile.php?username=$1&page_type=$2 [QSA,L]
```